# Is doing wget honoring robots legal scraping?

Tags: wget

I am creating a database as part of my project, I need to scrape  players pages of the website(nhl.com). I am planning to use wget for this, However the site's terms of service say that unauthorized scraping is not permitted.

So is what I am doing illegal? If yes, what would be the legal way to do this?

Comment: It's a violation of the terms of service.  You may find your IP banned.  Whether it's against the law is a different matter, probably depends on where you are located, and is not a programming question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a legal question.

Comment: This is a legal question more than a technical one.  However, I feel if your wget submits a request, and they honor that request by responding to it, they don't have much grounds to complain.

Comment: @abelenky how do I know if my wget is honoring the code?

Comment: @Dude - If they have a robots.txt file, read what it says.  If they don't, the code does not apply.

Comment: @abelenky - What you "feel" and what the law actually says are different things.  (And I know you are not a lawyer because a real lawyer would not say such a thing :-) )

Comment: @StephenC not to argue unnecessarily because I get what you are saying. But my page is not disallowed in robots.txt. Does it make any difference.

Comment: @Dude.  Your page is not relevant.  It is their page that matters.  And their robots.txt lists a number of trees on their sites that no crawler is supposed to crawl.  Besides, whether "robots.txt" trumps a ToS is not "settled law", AFAIK.

Answer (score 1):

> So is what I am doing illegal?

Yes.

> If yes, what would be the legal way to do this?

Talk to the NHL.

- They may give you permission.  (For a school project)
- They may require you to pay for a license.
- They may say No.  If they say No, then you need to find another source for your data.

---

Or you could just take a risk, ignore the legalities ... and hope that NHL doesn't decide to sue you.

Or if this is just a school project, then make up some imaginary player details.

Comment: It may be totally legal if he's located in Lower Elbonia.  There is no settled international law on web scraping.

Comment: Ermm ... given the US court system's willingness to overreach, I wouldn't recommend taking the risk.  Even in Elbonia.  Besides, why would someone in Elbonia be even remotely interested in the NHL.  (The Elbonian Mud Hockey League is much more interesting.  :-) )

Comment: How is it any different from manually saving pages?

Comment: It probably isn't.  Manually saving pages is most likely a breach of NHL copyright.  At least technically.  Anyhow, it is >>the US Courts<< that you would need to convince, and it would cost you lost of money before you got the chance to do that.  Besides, IANAL: IYWLA TTAL.

Comment: okay gotcha. Thanks for the advice, What IANAL: IYWLA TTAL.? looked it up could not find anything

Comment: I am not a lawyer.  If you want legal advice, talk to a lawyer.